# How Can I remove the extension Gridline from my graph?

Tags: graph, highcharts, gridlines

I design my graph using Highchart. But I can not customize it using CSS and js. Now this time I can't remove the extra grid line from the chart that I have shown in my screenshot. I try to modify d="M 77.5 45 L 77.5 365" from my code, but I can't get it to work. How can I solve this problem!
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot for clarity:

[Screenshot](https://postimg.cc/RWtZbvxV)

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the axis to start or end on a tick. Use this option with the minPadding option to control the axis start or maxPadding for end.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
  }]
});
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.endOnTick

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/305z7yf1/1/

---

EDITED

I simplified your example, to your goals.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/305z7yf1/2/

Comment: I'm trying to add minPadding  and maxPadding  for xAxis with startOnTick and endOnTick But its not working.

Comment: Show me your example, that might better understand what's going on in your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Bithy/ng1k5h70/53/

Comment: I'm sharing my code on jsfiddle

Comment: Ok, thanks, try to simplify your case to a working version.

Comment: I simplified your example, to your goals, is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/305z7yf1/2/

Comment: It worked but still have some issues. I want to remove the numbering(1 to 24) of xAxis. I don't need any numbering of xAxis.

Comment: Use [xAxis.labels.enabled](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.enabled) to turn off labels, for remove tick on xAxis chose [xAxis.tickWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickWidth). Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/305z7yf1/3/